# How to snap area light to a face?

Tags: faces, lighting

Snapping/gluing/connecting area light to an object face (pointing outwards from face). Is that even possible? I am not able to enter edit mode when cliking on area light. I wanted to create a simple effect: making a rotating cube with 4 area lights with different colors, pointing in 4 different directions, which I would snap to 4 different faces of cube. I first wanted to do that with simple rotating of the area light, but its only rotating around its axis - I am not able to change pivot point so that it would rotate with cube faces. I hope I am writing this in an understandable way.. how would you do that? Playing around with constraints somehow?
A begginer question, of course..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after snapping the cube to the face,  first select the area light and then control+ select the cube, so they are both selected.   and go to the **object menu** and choose **parent** and **object** to parent it.

The area light will then be listed under the cube in your outliner and will maintain its position on the cube when you rotate the cube.

Sometimes it may be helpful to parent everything to an "empty", but this is optional.

Comment: thank you so much!! it worked, it didn´t come to my mind to try it with parenting objects. you saved me!